# What is xrotor micro 30A?

Tags: drone

I was watching a video on how to build your own drone and this is one of the items. I tried to understand what it actually does but I couldn´t find any simple information.

I would like to know:
- what it does and
- if it could be replaced by an arduino

Thanks !!

Here is the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQib0sAhUc4

Comment: What video?  I'm sure some contact would help.

Comment: this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQib0sAhUc4

Comment: And where in the video does it talk about this thing?  Do I have to watch the whole 16 minutes to help you?  I don't want to do that.  Please be a little considerate here.

Comment: Ok, don't help me then. Is that simple haha

Comment: Why don't you add a time stamp to the link, to set the video playing from exactly the correct point? You add `&t=XXX` to the end of the URL. Where `XXX` is the time in seconds. It's quite simple, and it would help people who have the same issue, from having to watch the whole video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XROTOR MICRO is an ESC, which means Electronic Speed Control. It is essentially the motor driver in a quadcopter. Most quadcopter use brushless motors, because they are more fitted for the fast speeds of the propeller. But brushless motors aren't as easy to drive as simple DC motors. The current through the different coils has to be commutated depending on the current speed of the motor. The ESC does this for you and takes a PWM wave as input, whose duty cycle marks the requested speed. 30A is the current specification for this ESC. For more information google brushless motor.

> if it could be replaced by an arduino

Short answer: No.

Long answer: An ESC is a highly specialized device, which is very fast and drives high currents. It may be possible to build something like an ESC with an Arduino in it's heart, but this would be a dumb way to waste your time. The Arduino would be busy controlling the motor, so that it would not be able to do anything else. If you look at how many different peripherals the Arduino embodies, this is a total waste. Also the Arduino cannot drive these high currents by itself. You would have to add extra components to do this. If you are able to build this, it would be much bigger than a normal ESC.

All in all: If you aren't a crack in electronics and want to try this just for achieving, then you should simply buy an ESC for your drone project. Mostly Arduinos have vanished from modern drones, because there are many boards, that are better fitted for this.

Comment: Thanks you very much for that very complete answer! I appreciate it Chris !